# mongoose, populate V.S another query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

my case is:

I have `postSchema` and `commentSchema`, like this:

```
const postSchema = new Schema({
  comments: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Comment'
    }
  ]
}

const commentSchema = new Schema({
  post: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Post'
  }
}
```

If I know the `post._id`, I want to query the `post` documents and `comment` documents.

I think there are two way:

1. `popluate`: `Post.findById(post._id).populate('Comment').exec()`
2. start another query:

`Post.findById(post._id).exec()`

`Comment.find({post: new Types.ObjectId(post._id)}).exec()`

So, which is better? Or, when to use `populate` and when to start another query?

Comment: So `.populate()` actually performs "another query". it's not magic, but just a convenient way to issue that "other query". In all honesty your first point of call generally should be [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) these days, as it does at least make that action on the server. But you also should grasp some concept of "embedding" as well, because you are just really not meant to continue the same usage patterns as with a relational database when using a database designed to break those patterns.